# An Integral Equation for the Square of a Laguerre Polynomial

Tags: integration, bessel-functions, laguerre-polynomials

The following integral equation was presented back in the late 30's by Watson and Szego (Journal of the London Mathematical Society) but I cannot access the journal. Any ideas on a proof ?

$$e^{-x} x^{\alpha } L_n^{\alpha
   }(x){}^2=\int_0^{\infty } J_{2 \alpha
   }\left(2 \sqrt{x y}\right)
   e^{-y} y^{\alpha }
   L_n^{\alpha }(y){}^2 \, dy$$

where $L_n^{\alpha }(x)$ is the generalized Laguerre polynomial and $J_{2 \alpha }(z)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: Could you provide us with the reference for this formula?

Comment: An Integral Equation for the Square of a Laguerre Polynomial, G. N. Watson
Journal of the London Mathematical Society, Volume s1-11, Issue 4, October 1936, Pages 256–261, https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-11.4.256

Comment: this is a special case of a more general formula discussed recently at MathOverflow, see https://mathoverflow.net/a/396005/11260 (take $m=n$, $\nu=2\sigma$ in the formula quoted there). A proof by Szegö is [here](https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s1-12/3/162/831880?redirectedFrom=fulltext) (behind a paywall, you can email me for a copy).